# Ask dialog saves in the wrong map

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When asked to choose a savefile location, I'll choose a map called "timelapse".
but the pictures are saved in the map before the timelapse. as in;
/home/pi instead of /home/pi/timelapse

It appears I accidentally put a default save location in the code? because it won't change the location, but I never coded it should specifically safe in /home/pi

I've tried adding manually a "/" to the text in the hope it would open the timelapse map, but I get an error with permission denied.
Creating a different submap didn't work, it still saves in /home/pi

```
class Capture:
    def __init__(self, waittime=30):
        self.capture_stop = False
        self.capture_waittime = waittime
        self.thread = None
        self.capture_running = False
        self.folder = ''


    def capture_worker(self):
        self.capture_running = True

        try:
            with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
                camera.resolution = (1024, 768)

                for filename in camera.capture_continuous(self.folder+'-{timestamp:%H-%M-%S-%f}.jpg'):
                  i = 0
                  while i < self.capture_waittime:
                      time.sleep(0.1)
                      i += 0.1
                      if self.capture_stop:
                        return
        finally:
            self.capture_running = False
            self.capture_stop = False

    def start(self):
        if not self.capture_running:
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.capture_worker)
            self.capture_stop = False
            self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.capture_running:
            self.capture_stop = True

    def isRunning(self):
        return self.capture_running

    def setWaitTime(self, waittime):
        self.capture_waittime = waittime

    def setFolder(self, folder):
        capture.setFolder(folder)
        self.folder = folder




capture = Capture()


def startButton():
    interval = float(var_2.get())
    capture.setWaitTime(interval)
    capture.start()


def stopButton():
    capture.stop()


def chooseDir():
        root.folder = filedialog.askdirectory(
        parent=root, initialdir="/home/pi/", title='Please choose a save location')
```

I expect the pictures to be saved in the map I specifically chose. I also hope to receive some criticism on my ask dialog code so that I can improve it.

Comment: I realized that I was using initialdir wrong and corrected it, I made a few changes to the code, however, the issue has not been resolved and my timelapse will only save in /home/pi

Comment: you should use `os.path.join(folder, filename)` to create correct path.

Comment: if you have problem with permission then maybe you have to check directory's permission first. Do you run it with `cron` ? `cron` may run it as different user, with different permission and then you may have to change directiory's permission for all users.

Comment: @furas, use os.path.join(folder, filename) instead of camera.capture_continuous?
I'll provide the error reports with my next questions, thanks for the tip!
I'm not familiar with cron? I run the program on a raspberry pi?

Comment: use `os.path.join(folder, filename)` instead of  `folder+"/"+filename` or similar. In your code it means `camera.capture_continuous( os.path.join(self.folder, '-{timestamp:%H-%M-%S-%f}.jpg') )`

Comment: I don't run it with cron. The code is to be run when a timelapse is needed for a machine with an error. so on demand. Not in some continuous way where it will restart on its own.

Comment: I think I understand now, because with the os.path.join it will get the permission it needs to save the file in the given directory?

Comment: @furas, I tried what you advice and messed around with it for a bit. However, it will still save the pictures in /home/pi. even when selected a subfolder in /home/pi/timelapse/1, it still will save in the /pi map. is it saving there because of the code that is currently there? or did I unknowingly put a location in my code?
And I don't get an error code that I could share.

Comment: it should be checked at start - run `print(self.folder)` before `capture_continuous`. I think it is empty string. You have `self.folder=''` in `__init__` and I don't see where you change it. You assign `filedialog.askdirectory` to `root.folder` but not to `self.folder` or `capture.folder`.

Comment: @furas. You're right. Self.folder was empty. When I changed it to root, it worked and saved in the wanted location. Does that mean that the other def's are unnecessary? Or should I to minimize errors, attach the string to self.folder and use that in the capture class?

Comment: in Python we prefer to assign value directly to variable `self.folder = ...`. In your code it will be `capture.folder = filedialog.askdirectory(...)`. and you don't need `def setFolder()`.